# parse.com a query between two classes

Tags: objective-c, parse-platform, pfquery

** Edit : sorry I had to edit my question to clean out the other users i had so i delete everything.

so i manage to make some kind of relation between two users in one table on parse, this is how it's look : 
[image]

my class is NewChat and the user 'XcnKqF0tmO' is my Current user. 
i'm trying to create an query to receive a text ( the text is : hello) from another class called phoneNumber : 
[image]

as you can see the receiver 'T9kDJwePc' (on the first picture)  is the same user 'ZZ6mRK..' (on the second picture. 
what i'm trying to do is to create a query from the Sender 'XcnKqf0tmO' (1st picture) to the T9kPDJwePc who is actually ( if i click on the reciever name ) is ZZ6MRKr5J1 and get the text
" hello " into my TextField. I tried the following combination which didn't work :

```
  PFQuery *newOne = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"NewChat"];
// [newOne includeKey:@"reciever"]; <--- i tried with this line and with it
[newOne whereKey:@"sender" equalTo:[PFUser currentUser]];

PFQuery *phoneNumber = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"phoneNumber"];
[phoneNumber whereKey:@"objectId" matchesKey:@"reciever" inQuery:newOne];
[phoneNumber findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {

    NSLog(@"  object %@", objects);

}];
```

my query return with no result , my NSLOG show : "  object ( ) ".
why I have no results ? since the receiver name on the first image and the object ID on the second image are equal...

Comment: What do you get if you write NSLog(@"objects: %d", [objects count]); instead?

Comment: I must admit that I find your model a little confusing. How do you relate a "NewChat" object (which is kind of a bad name, as chats made last week are no longer "new chats"...) to the phoneNumber objects? And why are chat messages written in objects called "phoneNumber"?

Comment: lol, the reason I called it NewChat is because I did a lot of testing, those names are only for testing the idea, that's all. when i'm going to have a success with my query of course i'm going to change it. the reason the chat messages are written in the "phoneNumber" object is because the Username on the receiver User and the Object Id on the phoneNumber are the same User ID, so I thought instead have a lot of tables i can manange with two tables. but I still don't understand why my query has no result since Object Id and the receiver name are the same ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the pointer `nrlsl9lkvt` on the first picture points NOT to the record with the testing123 text, but to the record below. The phoneNumber record with the testing123 text has objectId o5igPWMaat, not nrlsl9lkvt.

You can get the text by quering for the NewChat object and use

```
[query includeKey:@"receiver"];
```

to ensure the phoneNumber object is downloaded as well. Just add a text to the right object in phoneNumber, and you're all set

**UPDATE**

Since you edited your question:

Your query should return the object you want (with objectId T9kPD...). Did you try the log statement I suggested? `NSLog(@"objects: %d", [objects count]);`

To get the text you want:

```
PFObject *object = [objects lastObject];  // Since your query should return only 1 object
NSLog(object[@"text"]);  // The "text" property of the object returned
```

If you're only interested in one object (like above), or KNOW there will only be one object, you should probably use `getFirstObjectInBackgroundWithBlock`: instead of `findObjectsInBackground...`. This will return one object instead of an array, and remove the need to call `[objects lastObject];`

Comment: I'm so sorry I had to Edit my question to clear out some of the users which confuse me. i'm so thankful for your time, please take a look at it again.

Comment: can you please recommend a way to get through it ?

Comment: I have updated my answer based on your updated question.

Comment: just wanted to drop by and say your are genius ! i did couple of modifications but use the same concept , it's all work now , thank you for your time.

Comment: Glad you got it working. Good luck with your project